# Discord.py trouble with move_member()

Tags: python, discord

Im having trouble with using `move_member()` for a python bot. The purpose of the command is to "kick" a user by moving them to a channel, then deleting it so that they disconnect from the voice call, but do not need an invite back to the server. I am aware that just moving a user accomplishes this purpose, but I would like for a user to disconnect instead.

```
import discord
import random
import time
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='with fire'))
    print("Logged in as " + bot.user.name)
    print(discord.Server.name)


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick(ctx,victim):
    await bot.create_channel(message.server, "kick", type=discord.ChannelType.voice)
    await bot.move_member(victim,"kick")
    await bot.delete_channel("bad boi")

bot.run('TOKEN_ID')
```

the line gives the error:

> The channel provided must be a voice channel

```
await bot.move_member(victim,"kick")
```

and this line gives this error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

```
await bot.delete_channel("kick")
```

Im pretty sure you have to get the channel id instead of "kick", but I don't see exactly how to do so, because the code below isnt working, even when I replace 
`ChannelType.voice` to `discord.ChannelType.voice`

```
discord.utils.get(server.channels, name='kick', type=ChannelType.voice)
```

Comment: Just to be on the same page, you ***can not*** move a member to a voice chat if the user isn’t already in a voice chat. Discord just dosnt support that.

Comment: It seems like OP wants to make a voice chat kick and not an actual kick. If so, it would be the next obvious thing that the OP is not kicking someone who's not in a voice chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete_channel('kick')` will not work because you need to pass in a `channel` object and not a string.

You do not need to use discord.utils to get the channel you want. The `create_channel` returns a channel object, so you should be able to use that.

But, you do need to get the `Member` object that you're going to kick. You also made the mistake of referencing `message.server` rather than `ctx.message.server`

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick(ctx, victim):
    victim_member = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.members, name=victim)
    kick_channel = await bot.create_channel(ctx.message.server, "kick", type=discord.ChannelType.voice)
    await bot.move_member(victim_member, kick_channel)
    await bot.delete_channel(kick_channel)
```

Now if you're using rewrite library, you would have to do the following

```
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, victim):
    victim_member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, name=victim)
    kick_channel = await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel("kick")
    await victim_member.move_to(kick_channel, reason="bad boi lul")
    await kick_channel.delete()
```

As abccd mentioned in the comments, this is evaluated as a string, which will not guarantee the fact that you'll be kicking the right person. `discord.utils.get` will grab the first result, and not necessarily the correct user if multiple users have the same name.

A better approach would be to use @user or to use UserIDs. Here's an example in the old library

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick(ctx):
    victim = ctx.message.mentions[0]
    kick_channel = await bot.create_channel(ctx.message.server, "kick", type=discord.ChannelType.voice)
    await bot.move_member(victim,kick_channel)
    await bot.delete_channel(kick_channel)
```

I would highly recommend to start using the rewrite library since it's much more Pythonic and it's going to be the new library in the future anyways.

Comment: The only problem to your almost-complete answer is that `discord.utils.get` returns the first member with the given name, it’s possible to have multiple members in a channel to have the same name (its very possible in a highly-populated channel). The victim might not be the actual member the OP actually wants to kick

Comment: Yes, you are correct. A better way to do this is to either reference the member through @ or giving the userID. I will edit my answer to use the @ as an example, but it's up to OP to decide how he wishes to implement (or implement both)

Comment: It worked, and its for my own server with <15 people most of the time with all unique nicknames. I chose the 3rd one, and it works as intended. However, i only know a reasonable amount of python, and the API is quite hard to read for me. Any pages I can read up on how to work with code like this?

Comment: [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/) is the docs for the Rewrite library. I agree that docs can be difficult to read sometimes. You just have to grind through it. You can also try to find other bots that are open sourced such as mine: [here](https://github.com/xNinjaKittyx/KoyomiBot) and read their source code. Also there's a discord server for all the APIs where you can get easy accessible help, which the invite link is [here](https://discord.gg/discord-api)

Comment: Thanks, ive already used the Discord Server before, but they act like you are supposed to know about the API and the ins and outs of discord beforehand, but dont offer as much help as they do on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Discord documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.delete_channel), the call to `delete_channel` expects a parameter of type `Channel`.

For more information on the `Channel` class, refer to [the Channel documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#channel)

If I understand what you're attempting to do, for your code to run as expected, you would **need to maintain a reference to the channel** you are using as your temporary channel, and then change your offending line to:

```
await bot.delete_channel(tmp_channel)
```